# use a WSDL with username+password in mule?

Tags: wsdl, mule

I have a wsdl with this url (`http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode`) that set username + password on it. Now I want to use this url as a **wsdlLocation** in my .mflow (configurationXML) file such as thes codes:

```
    <flow name="PostCode" doc:name="PostCode">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8085"
            path="postcode/service" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
        <cxf:proxy-service doc:name="post_code" service="PostcodeWSService"
            wsdlLocation="http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl" namespace="http://service.post.net/"
            payload="body" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode"  doc:name="HTTP" encoding="UTF-8" responseTimeout="1000000"  exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="post_code" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

but when I start-up it in MULE I have these errors:

---

```
    ERROR 2013-02-18 09:55:25,726 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1305)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1807)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.createMessageProcessorChain(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:163)
    at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.getMessageProcessorChain(AbstractEndpoint.java:517)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:104)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:259)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:143)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:139)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:249)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.1.2:9094/iran/postcode?wsdl
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:174)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.http.localhost.9094.iran.postcode"
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:122)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:259)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:143)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:139)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:249)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:151)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: SERVICE_CREATION_MSG
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.createMessageProcessorChain(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:163)
    at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.getMessageProcessorChain(AbstractEndpoint.java:517)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:104)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: SERVICE_CREATION_MSG
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1807)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:94)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:54)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1305)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

---

My codes work when thare is no username+password on WSDL, but Now that it has username+password my codes don't work?

How can I pass that username+password in my codes for extending and then working my wsdl without any problem??????????

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I changed my codes same as below:

(I encoded my password)

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
<service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
```

```
<http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8085"
    path="MyService/Service"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
<cxf:proxy-service 
    payload="envelope" 
    service="PostcodeWSService"
    wsdlLocation="http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/postcode?wsdl"
    namespace="http://service.post.net/"
    validationEnabled="true" doc:name="SOAP" />     
</http:inbound-endpoint>

<outbound-endpoint 
    address="http://192.168.1.2:8082/postcode"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic">
<cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true"  doc:name="SOAP"/>   
</outbound-endpoint>
```

but again I have these errors:

```
ERROR 2013-02-19 08:03:17,092 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/postcode?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1305)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1807)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.createMessageProcessorChain(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:163)
    at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.getMessageProcessorChain(AbstractEndpoint.java:517)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:104)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:259)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:143)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:139)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:249)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/postcode?wsdl
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:174)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.http.localhost.8085.MyService.Service"
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:122)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:259)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:143)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:139)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:249)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:151)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: SERVICE_CREATION_MSG
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.createMessageProcessorChain(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:163)
    at org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.getMessageProcessorChain(AbstractEndpoint.java:517)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:104)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: SERVICE_CREATION_MSG
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1807)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.getEndpointName(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.build(AbstractInboundMessageProcessorBuilder.java:66)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.config.FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.initialise(FlowConfiguringMessageProcessor.java:94)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/iran/postcode?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:808/postcode?wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.ProxyServiceConfiguration.getEndpointName(ProxyServiceConfiguration.java:54)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/postcode?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1305)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you browse or curl `http://postcode:%2A%25P%40%24T-C%40DE%25%2A@192.168.1.2:8082/postcode?wsdl` does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **wsdlLocation** using the following format:

```
http://username:password@192.168.1.2:9095/postcode?wsdl
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And does your password contains any char that you might need to escape?

Comment: this is my passwprd :  *%P@$T-C@DE%*